# Sphinix GUI trainer Failed to compile

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmusphinx

i am trying to create ASR system for my native language called amharic and my plan is to make an aquastic model without toomuch effort. for that i thought i could use ASTRA(Advanced Sphinix Trainer ) which is made using QT. but the thing is there is only source code , no compiled binaries and wheni try to compile it using QT 5.1 mingw (X64) i get this errors .

```
S:\Lite\astra\audio_play.cpp:-1: In member function 'void audio_play::pause()':
S:\Lite\astra\audio_play.cpp:31: error: 'SIGSTOP' was not declared in this scope
S:\Lite\astra\audio_play.cpp:31: error: 'kill' was not declared in this scope
S:\Lite\astra\audio_play.cpp:38: error: 'SIGCONT' was not declared in this scope
S:\Lite\astra\audio_play.cpp:38: error: 'kill' was not declared in this scope
S:\Lite\astra\audio_play.cpp:-1: In member function 'void audio_play::stop_record()':
S:\Lite\astra\audio_play.cpp:50: error: 'kill' was not declared in this scope
```

Source code location of ASTRA -- [AStra Trainer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/astra-sphinx/)

Comment: That's UNIX signal stuff. Are you sure Windows is supported?

Comment: nope , i though QT framework is supported in every platform. just like java]

Comment: Well, the Qt library is, but that doesn't prevent people from mixing platform-specific non-portable code with Qt.

Comment: well thats too bad , i have to waste my time remaking the software. i wish there was tools that i dont have to remember command lines to train speech dataset. which is time consuming and prone to error.

Comment: You could also try to port that tool instead of rewriting it. If you're lucky, it's just a couple non-portable lines of code and that's it. This signal handling you probably just could wrap in #ifdef Q_OS_UNIX ... #endif.